# Ansible -playbook when deb not installed install

Tags: ansible

im trying to write a playbook and i want to check if a deb package is installed and if not installed then install

so iv'e tried so far using the package_facts module and i can't figure this out

```
   - name: Gather package facts
     package_facts:
       manager: auto

   - name: Debug if package is present
     debug:
       msg: 'yes, mypackage is present'
     when: '"besagent" in ansible_facts.packages'
     register: besagent

   - name: Debug if package is absent
     debug:
       msg: 'no, mypackage is absent'
     when: '"besagent" not in ansible_facts.packages'
```

and this is the command to install the deb

```
- name: Install_BigFix_DEB
     apt: deb="/usr/BigFix/BESAgent-9.5.11.191-debian6.amd64.deb"
     sudo: true
```

So i see if the package is installed or not and i have a command to install the package but how do i make it happen automatically.
If BigFix agent is not installed Then install the agent?

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2):

Ansible operations are idempotent in nature. If you are using Ansible modules then you don't need to check if deb package is installed or not. Ansible will take care of it. If the package is not installed it will install. Else it will skip.

You can directly use

```
- name: Install_BigFix_DEB
  apt: deb="/usr/BigFix/BESAgent-9.5.11.191-debian6.amd64.deb"
  sudo: true
```

As per Ansible [document](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html): 
An operation is idempotent if the result of performing it once is exactly the same as the result of performing it repeatedly without any intervening actions.

Comment: Thanks for the replay!! i will check it out and update!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check if the package is already installed or not.

The `apt` module take care of that.

If the package is already installed, `apt` will do nothing and return a `status: ok`,

if not, it will install it and return a `status: changed`.